# Is there any good book regarding Image Processing Algorithms for Feature Extraction and Matching which gives examples in MATLAB?

Tags: image-processing, matlab, computer-vision

I have been looking to implement feature extraction and matching in MATLAB. For this, I've read many algorithms, but i'm not able to understand how to implement these in MATLAB. Is there any Book related to this topic which is based on MATLAB? i.e. gives exapmles and sample codes in MATLAB?
I have read Gonzolez and there is no other book that deals with Image Processing Algorithms with help of MATLAB.

Answer (score 2):

you may refer Feature Extraction & Image Processing
 By Mark Nixon, Alberto S Aguado.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of information on feature detection, extraction, and matching in the [Computer Vision System Toolbox documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/local-feature-detection-and-extraction.html).